# Select sheet defined as date

Tags: vba, date, excel

I do have a workbook where multiple sheets are named based on date (in format MMDDD). This macro should loop trough all date sheet (like 01OCT, 02OCT, .... 30OCT) select range and copy it into new sheet.

Selecting cells, copying them and so is not really problem, and that is working perfectly. However I do have a problem defining sheet name. I would like user in the beginning define month and number of days in month and month using InputBox.

So if user select month = "FEB" and DaysMonth = 28, I would like macro to loop trough sheets named 01FEB, 02FEB, 03FEB, .... 28FEB.

```
    Sub Merge_whole_month()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Dim month As String

            month = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter month in format MMM", _
                  Title:="Month")

        Dim DaysMonth As Long

            DaysMonth = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter number of days in month", _
                  Title:="Days")

    'create new sheet for results
        Sheets.Add.Name = "Merge"

    'loop
    For i = 1 To DaysMonth
        i = Format(i, "##")

        Sheets(i & month).Activate 'here is the problem

    'select cell G3, then all "non-empty" cells to the right and down and COPY

        Range(Range("G3", Range("G3").End(xlToRight)), Range("G3", Range("G3").End(xlToRight)).End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Merge").Activate 'activate sheet where cells needs to be copied

    'find last cell in 2nd row in sheet
        lastCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lastCol = lastCol + 1

            Cells(1, lastCol) = i & month   'log date and month in cell above

                Cells(2, lastCol).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste               'Paste

    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You should not be using *i* as an integer to increment the `For ... Next` then swap it into a string midstream. Use something like `Sheets(Format(i, "00") & month).Activate` to select the worksheet. Get rid of any other manipulation of *i*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the facto that `i = Format(i, "##")` does not make `i` less than 10 appear as `01` etc. To fix this i would do this:

```
Dim sDate As String
sDate = CStr(i)
If Len(sDate) < 2 Then
    sDate = "0" & sDate
End If
```

Place that code within your for-loop before `Sheets(i & month).Activate` and remove `i = Format(i, "##")`.

EDIT:

It also seems that for me using `Format(i, "0#")` gives the string you were looking for. However you will still need to assign this to a String variable or change `Sheets(i & month).Activate` to `Sheets(Format(i, "0#") & month).Activate`.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755(v=office.15).aspx) is the documentation on the `Format()` function. I suggest reading it.